# How to Query EntityFramework.Core 3.0 DbContext with ThenInclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I must be missing something simple.  I have created a project to hold data models.  I have added the following packages:

- Microsoft.EntifyFrameworkCore (3.1.0)
- Microsoft.EntitiFrameworkCore.SqlServer (3.1.0)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (3.1.0)

I created the models using the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=MyServer;database=MyDB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=MyUserId;Password=myPassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Now I have a context called MyDBContext.  However, I don't seem to have the methods required to write the LINQ queries I was expecting.  I was hoping to be able to write something like this:

```
var pt = context.Patient.Where(p => p.PatientId == 1234)
                        .Include(pa => pa.PatientAddress)
                        .ThenInclude(....)
```

ThenInclude is not available.  What am I missing?

On a side note, I was expecting the DbSets to be pluralized.  Why didn't this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

First you have to include the extensions in your class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

**Original answer**

It exists, but:

> Code completion still does not offer up properties in ThenInclude.
>   e.g., Author not an option in the docs example:
>
> ```
> var blogs = context.Blogs
>        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
>            .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
>        .ToList();
> ```
>
> When entered manually, compiles with no errors or underlining and runs
>   correctly.

See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237#issuecomment-562997436

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not even getting .ThenInclude in intellisense and the project will not compile if I add it.  Error:  IQueryable<Patient>' does not contain a definition for 'ThenInclude' and no accessible extension method 'ThenInclude' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<Patient>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: And there it is.  I wish code examples would include required "using" statements.  Thank you!